# Hide element if it contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code on my ecommerce website.

I would like to search  to check whether it contains "0.00"

If it does contain "0.00" I would like to hide the parent div containing the price

This is because we want the product to appear online but even though it cannot be purchased, the price is still displayed, so we don't want people to be confused if they see the price as £0.00.

```
<div class="ct_pd_item_price ct_pd_item_value">
<span itemprop="price">
<span class="ct_currencyCode">GBP</span>
<span class="ct_currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</span>    
</div>
```

Is this possible using some form of javascript?

Comment: The HTML markup is invalid. It is missing a closing span tag.

Comment: @epascarello , why so ?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Because it is missing a closing tag.

Comment: @epascarello u mean </span> ? is missing ?

Comment: That would be a closing tag and that would be what is missing.

Comment: @epascarello The error was added by the edit by Velthune. The initial HTML was nasty but valid (nested spans).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't change your HTML, it's a little tedious because the text must be cleand from the currencyCode and currencySymbol. A way to do this is to clone the div and then take the text :

```js
$(".ct_pd_item_price.ct_pd_item_value").filter(function(){
   return $(this).clone().find('.ct_currencyCode, .ct_currencySymbol').remove().end().text().trim()=="0.00"
}).hide()
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/dahika/1/edit)

Of course a cleaner HTML, maybe with the value in a data attribute, would be easier to deal with.

Comment: Do you want to say any explanation for the above code?

Comment: Can you prooflink this? I doubt you

Comment: @skip405 - We can't doubt dystroy. Because he already proved in SO

Comment: @Sudharsan I make errors too. Here I at first wrongly assumed that the real HTML would have the value in a dedicated span (what I would have done).

Comment: @Sudharsan, I don't mean to offend anyone, simply asking to make an online link of an answer that was completely different from the current one :) Right now my comment is out of place, surely

Answer (score 0):

Another way with a regular expression

```
$('[itemprop="price"]').each(
    function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (elem.text().match(/[^\d]0\.00/)) {
            elem.closest(".ct_pd_item_price.ct_pd_item_value").hide();
        }
    }
);
```

Pulls out the text and it will be `£0.00` so match that the price is not `[anynumber]0.00`

Comment: +1 because I don't get why this should be downvoted and it's probably to late to ask the downvoter