# Hiding DIV if it contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked a similar question yesterday ([Hide element if it contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24933863/3220812))

I have since tried to adapt the code suggested by dystroy to hide a DIV on another page.

This is the page HTML:

```
<div class="ct_pl_product_price">
<a class="ct_pl_product_link" href="/link/to/item">£0.00</a>
</div>
```

As before, I would like to hide the "ct_pl_product_price" DIV if it contains £0.00

This is the script I have tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".ct_pl_product_price").filter(function(){
   return $(this).clone().find('.ct_pl_product_link').remove().end().text().trim()=="0.00"
}).hide()

});
```

I think that makes sense (if I've interpreted dystroys' code correctly) but it doesn't appear to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `:contains` selector in this case:

```
$('.ct_pl_product_price:contains("£0.00")').hide()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Out of interest, I don't suppose you could explain why the other code didn't work?

Comment: @user3220812 well for a start you missed "£" in your equation

Comment: @user3220812: because, `find('.ct_pl_product_link').remove()` removes text in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:contains` selector:

```
$('.ct_pl_product_price:contains("0.00")').hide();
```

Or you can use `filter`, modifying the logic:

```
$(".ct_pl_product_price").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('0.00') != -1;
}).hide()
```

Note that `filter()` will be slightly faster.